# Saving List<T> as String

Tags: java

I've been trying to save a list of data as Strings, but when I try a method `.toString` on List, it returns address in memory instead of data.

```
public class Item {

    Integer price = 20;
    Integer modelNumber = 100;
    String description = "Description";
    String title = "Title";
    Boolean wasBought = true;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new Item());
    System.out.println(data.toString());
}
```

Comment: Answer, because this will get boring fast: create a method `toString(): String` in your `Item` class, otherwise it will print out a reference to the object instance. Use `String.format(formatString, fields...)` to do so.

Comment: "*trying to save a list of data as Strings*" how (and why - what are you trying to achieve)? What do you mean by ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: "Boxed" classes should arguably not be used for fields, unless they can remain uninitialized. Use `int` and `boolean` instead.

Comment: See Object.toString(). All IDEs can generate a toString(). Start there please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert List to json format string by json utils, e.g. jackson or fastjson, in case you may need to convert it to Objects later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `toString` function in your `Item` class. Add the following snippet into your `Item` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item{" +
            "price=" + price +
            ", modelNumber=" + modelNumber +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", wasBought=" + wasBought +
            '}';
}
```

Output:

```
[Item{price=20, modelNumber=100, description='Description', title='Title', wasBought=true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Lombok  (Add Lombok jar into classpath)  @ToString annotate for Item class, it will do the needful output  https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString